# How to send high rate of data ~30-100Hz to web server and/or bluetooth

Tags: android, websocket, httprequest

I'm currently working on a quadcopter that will use the sensors from an old android, 4.0.3, and I wanted to know what was the best way to send real-time data to a server through WiFi for logging (ie. every time the data updates with `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME`)

I'm currently using:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationVector, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGrav, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLumen, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

**Each request will send 3 floats.**

I understand I could just do a simple httprequest and send the data every time it updates, but I feel that it'll be hard for the phone to handle ~30-100 requests per minute and not get overloaded.

Another solution I was thinking was to store the data temporarily on the phone and have an event that fires every 20-33ms to send the data it has.

But, I'm still not sure if those are good solutions. If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

The main phone I will be using is the [HTC EVO 3D Specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Evo_3D) or possibly [SAMSUNG Galaxy S4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4)

As a side note the app will also have to send bluetooth data at a rate of ~25-33Hz to tell the motors how to move.

P.S. Is it possibly to create an HTML5 websocket to talk to the phone directly to show live data? As that would be a nice ideal solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A websocket sounds like a very good solution - keeping the socket open will avoid the overhead of setting up and tearing down a connection every time.

Have a look at http://autobahn.ws/android - I've only tried it briefly, but it seems to work very well.